# Why is the probability of a false positive not 0 for Freivald's Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, randomized

Freivald's algorithm (see the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freivalds%27_algorithm)) is a randomized algorithm for verifying whether the product of two $n \times n$-matrices $A$ and $B$ yields a given matrix $C$ (i.e. $AB = C$). The way this task is accomplished is to introduce a random vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and evaluate whether
$$A(Bv) = Cv$$
The claim is that if $AB \neq C$, then $AB v = Cv$ with probability at most $1/2$, and they provide a justification. Their argument for why 1/2 works makes some sense to me. What I don't understand is why this bound can't be improved further by the following argument:

**Claim:** Suppose that $AB \neq C$. Then for almost all choices of $v$ (i.e. with probability $1$), $AB v \neq Cv$.

**Proof of Claim:** Note that $AB v = Cv$ if and only if $(AB-C)v =0$. Let $D = AB-C$. Then $ABv = Cv$ if and only if $v \in \ker(D)$. Since $AB \neq C$, $D$ is not the $0$-matrix meaning that $\dim(\ker(D)) < n$. Hence, $\ker(D)$ is a proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and therefore has measure $0$. Thus, for almost all choices of $v$, $D v \neq 0$ meaning that $ABv \neq Cv$ with probability $1$.

Q.E.D.

Hence, if $AB v = Cv$, then $AB = C$ with probability $1$. Shouldn't this mean that the probability of failure in Freivald's algorithm is $0$ instead of $2^{-k}$?

Thanks.

Comment: By definition, Freivald's algorithm chooses only vectors $v$ whose entries equal $0$ or $1$. In that setting, $\frac12$ is the best possible bound even over $\Bbb Q$. You could propose a variant of the algorithm and ask about bounds for that....

Comment: Ah actually, this exists and is surprisingly recent. This arxiv post published in a journal in 2020 supplies such a variant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10449.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Algorithms can't work over $\mathbb{R}^n$, as you can't represent real numbers in finite space.  Also, you can't pick a number uniformly at random from $\mathbb{R}$.  Instead, usually we work over a finite field.

Then we can't do any better.  Suppose we are working in the finite field with two elements, $GF(2)$.  Suppose that

$$AB - C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then it is easy to verify that Frievald's algorithm is wrong with probability $1/2$, as $(AB-C)v = 0$ holds with probability $1/2$ when we select $v$ uniformly at random.  You can generalize this to a $n\times n$ matrix that is all zeros except for a single entry, and then the probability of false positive is $1/2$.

If you are working over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the same matrix $AB-C$ also provides a similar counterexample.  As [Greg Martin explains](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142247/why-is-the-probability-of-a-false-positive-not-0-for-freivalds-algorithm/142248?noredirect=1#comment299542_142247), Freivald's algorithm by definition chooses vectors uniformly at random from $\{0,1\}^n$, and then when $v$ is selected from this distribution, $(AB-C)v=0$ holds with probability $1/2$.  (And if you are wondering whether it is possible to do better by choosing $v$ differently, there is no way to choose a number uniformly at random from $\mathbb{Q}$, so it's not clear what distribution you would use.)

Comment: This is a good answer, and I appreciate it. However, in practice, I mainly multiply matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$. In that case, the same proof follows. In particular, when I perturb a LP for the simplex method to create nondegeneracy, I do exactly that and the justification also follows from hyperplanes being measure zero. Is there a reason why we should not do so in the rational case? Thanks again.

Comment: @KeimaKatsuragi, see edited answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you do a lot better by choosing $v$ from $\{1,2\}^n$ instead? It seems obvious that you don't want the zero vector in the distribution since that's a guaranteed false positive, and zero entries in the vector more generally cause problems when the difference matrix has lots of zero entries like in your example.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, nope, that doesn't help.  Consider $$AB-C = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\1&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You can sure tinker with the probability in various ways. For example, choosing $v$ in $\{0,\dots,2^n-1\}^n$ will decrease the probability to $2^{-n}$. However, no matter what you do, the probability is not $0$ (it is inversely proportional to the size of the sample set for each coordinate), and there is a trade off in that choosing $v$ from a larger sample set will increase the size of the numbers involved in the computation, hence increase the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: If you're careful, you may not increase the complexity by changing the sample space. You could for example choose your vector so that all entries are in $\{0,1\}$ except for one entry which is in $\{0,\dots, 2^{n}-1\}$. That one entry appears in at most $O(n)$ sums and products, and it increases the complexity of the sum/product by at most $O(n)$, so you only get an additional $O(n^2)$ factor, which is fine. There may still be some hope that the sample space that Frievalds used could be improved upon to yield a better bound.

Comment: Well, what I’d rather do is that when checking multiplication of $n\times n$ integer or rational matrices with entries of bitsize $m$, pick the vector $v$ in $\{0,\dots,2^m-1\}^n$. The point is that this will not significantly increase the complexity because *you’ve already paid the price*: you have to do arithmetic operations on numbers of size $\Omega(m)$ anyway. More formally, if $n$ and $m$ is as above, and I run the algorithm $k$ times independently with uniform $v\in\{0,\dots,2^r-1\}^n$, the probability of error is $2^{-kr}$, and the running time is $O(kn^2M(m+r))$ where $M$ is the ...

Comment: ... complexity of integer multiplication. Thus, if I want error $2^{-t}$, I need time $O\bigl(tn^2\frac{M(m+r)}r\bigr)$; since $M$ grows superlinearly, this is minimized for $r\approx m$, in which case the time is $O\bigl(tn^2\frac{M(m)}m\bigr)$, for $t\ge m$. This is $O(tn^2m)$ using schoolbook quadratic multiplication, and $O(tn^2\log m)$ using (theoretically) best known multiplication algorithms.